# Replace occurrences of a string inside a HTML string using Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a HTML string in Objective C.  `NSString *contentString;`

How do I replace the occurrences of a string inside this HTML string while preserving the HTML tags ?

I would use the statement `contentString = [contentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"string" withString : @"new string"];` but that will also replace the text within HTML tags. I need to preserve those. I am facing a similar problem while using 3rd party HTML parsers.

The contents of contentString are :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" lang="en"><head><link
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../RESOURCE/core.css" /><link
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../RESOURCE/inserts.css" /><link
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../RESOURCE/jquery-ui.css"
/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="../RESOURCE/jquery.qtip.css" /><link type="text/css"
rel="stylesheet" href="../RESOURCE/template-opus.css"
data-wundr-theme="true" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="../RESOURCE/font-scheme-opus.css?1395092689.864661"
data-wundr-font-scheme="true" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="../RESOURCE/color-scheme-opus.css?1395092689.864992"
data-wundr-color-scheme="true" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="../RESOURCE/paragraph-styles.css?1395092689.865252"
data-wundr-paragraph-style="true" /></head><body
data-wundr-page="content"><div class="wundr-guides" style="display:
none;"></div><div class="wundr-page-guide" style="display:
none;"></div><article data-wundr="chapter"
class="wundr-padding-regular"><header><h2
class="pw-par-style-chapter-number pw-par-style-big-letter"
data-wundr-key="chapter-number">1</h2><h1
class="pw-par-style" data-wundr-key="chapter-title"
contenteditable="true"
data-wundr-dummy="true">Chapter</h1></header><section
class="pw-par-style-body" data-wundr-epub-type="subchapter"
contenteditable="true"><p data-wundr-dummy="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec mauris lorem. Quisque
luctus velit cursus elit sodales vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque diam augue, varius vitae auctor eu,
malesuada in purus. Quisque dapibus justo sed nisi gravida malesuada.
Sed consequat enim condimentum lorem semper a iaculis mi consequat.
Donec euismod lobortis est, at tincidunt enim tempor id. Nunc id nunc
quis enim vehicula bibendum sed ut orci. Donec vehicula semper leo, a
auctor tortor bibendum sed. Quisque cursus sapien a eros convallis eget
molestie ligula dignissim. Fusce ullamcorper posuere augue et fermentum.
Integer at dolor sed lorem porttitor iaculis. Sed vitae felis id dolor
vulputate hendrerit ut sed nisl.</p><p data-wundr-dummy="true">Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec mauris
lorem. Quisque luctus velit cursus elit sodales vulputate. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque diam augue, varius
vitae auctor eu, malesuada in purus. Quisque dapibus justo sed nisi
gravida malesuada. Sed consequat enim condimentum lorem semper a iaculis
mi consequat. Donec euismod lobortis est, at tincidunt enim tempor id.
Nunc id nunc quis enim vehicula bibendum sed ut orci. Donec vehicula
semper leo, a auctor tortor bibendum sed. Quisque cursus sapien a eros
convallis eget molestie ligula dignissim. Fusce ullamcorper posuere
augue et fermentum. Integer at dolor sed lorem porttitor iaculis. Sed
vitae felis id dolor vulputate hendrerit ut sed
nisl.</p></section></article><div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Why would that replace the tags? Give a specific example of what you need to replace.

Comment: If I try to replace `Lorem` with `ReplacedText`, that will work without issues. But if I try to replace `chapter` with `ReplacedText`, that will replace the word chapter in the line of code `<h2
class="pw-par-style-chapter-number pw-par-style-big-letter"
data-wundr-key="chapter-number">`

Comment: Good. That clarifies your issue. There is no simple solution. You can't use basic search and replace. You could try parsing this xhtml and rebuilding it as you parse. Only do the search and replace on actual text and not tags or attributes or attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some basic logic (Probably Just a Bool) to check if you are inside or outside of an html tag. Only stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString if you are outside an html tag. Some of the snippets in this code will help you.

http://www.developerfeed.com/how-remove-html-tags-string-ios

```
  + (NSString *)flattenHtml: (NSString *) html {
    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: html];
    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

            [theScanner scanUpToString: @"<" intoString: NULL];

            [theScanner scanUpToString: @">" intoString: &text];

            // Only Replace if you are outside of an html tag
    } // while
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Works for the most part. The biggest bug is that if there's a `<` or a `>` in the text, then the entire parser will break

Comment: True, but that should not happen. They are reserved characters. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try using some javascript on it after loading it into the web view. That would also allow you to load some tools that could help like jQuery to make the job easier.